# creating a matrix from rows of another matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have an x-by-y matrix M, which i'm using to store x row vectors.

e.g.

```
M = [ 1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9 ]
```

Now say that I want to create another matrix N, which consists of these vectors disposed in a random order, some vectors may repeat some might not be used at all.

```
N = [ 4 5 6; 4 5 6; 1 2 3; 7 8 9; 4 5 6; ...]
```

Any suggestions?

I'm thinking of the following:

```
V = randi([x, 1], 1, length);
N = [ ];
for b = 1:length;
    c = V(b);
    N = [N; M(c)];
end
```

Where again x is the number of rows in the matrix M. I haven't been able to test this so I don't know if it works yet.

Comment: We are not here to test your code for you. If you don't own MATLAB simply use the free open source alternative octave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using `randi` correctly (please read the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html)). It looks like you have the input arguments backwards. You can also do this without a loop:

```
M = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
len = 10;                     % Number of rows in new matrix
V = randi(size(M,1), len, 1); % Random row indices
N = M(V,:)
```

which returns (randomly)

```
N =

     7     8     9
     7     8     9
     1     2     3
     7     8     9
     4     5     6
     1     2     3
     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9
     7     8     9
```

I also used `len` instead of `length`, which is the name of a commonly-used function.

Comment: Thank you. I'm still getting acquainted with MATLAB.